# How to change the MySQL workbench configuration path?

Tags: mysql-workbench, configuration-files

I am not able to find a option in MySQL workbench to change the default configuration directories. Currently it is pointing to C:/user/%AppData% in my windows.

Can someone help me on how to change this directory, because everyday this directory gets deleted for me due to some rules in my organization.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option in MySQL Workbench. Like any good citizen on Windows the application uses the path that is determined to store application data. I find it rather weird that it is a policy in your organization to destroy user data, as this fights directly against recommended practises.

Comment: Is there any configuration file which i can edit to change the default directory?

Comment: No, WB uses the system's standard paths for locating the configuration directory (home dir on Linux + Mac, AppData on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem this is how I solved it.

I'm running a surface book and installed MySQL on an external drive "D:"

Start the database from a command window:
(below is my path not the default)

1. Navigate to the "bin" folder

   D:\MySql\bin\
2. use "mysqld" command to start the database

   mysqld

   (note) this will run continuously until you shut the database down

Now your MySQL workbench should connect (well mine did)

To stop the database you will have to bring up another command window then type:

1. Navigate to the "bin" folder

   D:MySql\bin\
2. use "mysqladmin" to stop the database

   mysqladmin -u root shutdown

   (note) if your "root" user has a password you will have to use

   myslqadmin -u root -p "type your password here" shutdown